# How can I coordinate integration tests in a multi-container (Docker) system?

Tags: docker, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

I have inherited a system that consists of a couple daemons that asynchronously process messages.  I am trying to find a clean way to introduce integration testing into this system with minimal impact/risk on the existing programs.  Here is a very simplified overview of their responsibilities:

- Process 1 polls a queue for messages, and inserts a row into a DB for each one it dequeues.
- Process 2 polls the DB for rows inserted by Process 1, does some calculations, and then deposits a file into a directory on the host and sends an email.

These processes are quite old and complex, and I am strongly inclined to avoid modifying them in any way.  What I would like to do is put each of them in a container, and also stand up the dependencies (queue, DB, mail server) in other containers.  This part is straightforward, but what I'm unsure about is the best way to orchestrate these tests.  Since these processes consume and generate output asynchronously I will need to poll or wait for the expected outcome (mail sent, file created).

Normally I would just write a series of tests in a single test suite of my language of choice (Java, Go, etc), and make the setUp / tearDown hooks responsible for resetting the environment to the desired state.  But because these processes have a lot of internal state I am afraid I cannot successfully "clean up" properly after each distinct test.  This would be a problem if, for example, one test failed to generate the desired output in a specific period of time so I marked it as failed, but a subsequent test falsely got marked as passed because the original test case actually did output something (albeit much slower than anticipated) that was mistakenly attributed to the subsequent test.  For these reasons I feel I need to recreate the world between each test.

In order to do this the only options I can see are:

1. Use a shell script to actually run my tests -- having it bring up the containers, execute a single test file, and then terminate my containers for each test.
2. Follow my usual pattern of setUp / tearDown in my existing test framework but call out to `docker` to terminate and start up the containers between each test.

Am I missing another option?  Is there some kind of existing framework or pattern used for this sort of testing?